# Identifying "mismatch duplicates" with a Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure how to describe this one, so apologies for the vague title.

I'm trying to identify when a specific value in a column in Google Sheets appears more than once, but only if the value in a separate column is different. A visual will probably help here:

[image]

So in this scenario you can see that the `1111` ID is assigned to James twice and Nicole once. It's absolutely fine that `1111` is listed multiple times. But it's not good that it's assigned to more than one unique person. So my desire is for every row using the `1111` ID gets flagged with a formula (as seen in the 'Status' column) so that I can filter for it and handle the problem.

The example above uses names for the Owner, but that could be numbers instead.

Here is an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eBF3G6UAICgzUJdUA8onGyJiba0Wmu4DOK3U6-SQz7c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Owner is in column A and ID is in column B then, for Excel, you could put this in C2 and copy it to the other cells in column C:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2),"Good","Mismatch Detected")
```

It compares the count of the ID against the count of the ID and the name.  If the ID 1111 appears 3 times but James,1111 only appears 2 times there is a mismatch.

You probably want to change the A:A and B:B to be the range of your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in GS:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF((COUNTIF(A2:A&B2:B,A2:A&B2:B)=COUNTIF(B2:B,B2:B)),"Good","Bad"),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A&B2:B, A2:A&B2:B)=1, "mismatch", "good")))
```

[image]